# ASP.net canvas server control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering if anyone has come up with an ASP.net server tag for the HTML5 canvas?  I was thinking of something where I could declaritively define paths, curves; etc in the aspx markup, and the control would deliver the js to do this (perhaps with support for browser detection, and delivery of an emulation script for IE browsers.)

Maybe a good idea for a Codeplex project for me to start up?

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea, surely you'd just be abstracting away JavaScript, in the same way that ASP.NET Webforms abstracts away HTML/CSS and JavaScript/Ajax, which is considered by many a bad idea (hence why we have ASP.NET MVC). Really Canvas is a client-side technology so you should learn client-side programming if you want to use it, not use some translation layer.

Answer (score 3):

I started an open source project that includes a canvas, but I wasn't too sure which features people would want to include.  As Ironfoot explains, it seems like canvas was more designed for more use on the client side.  I have done a signature capture using the canvas and the amount of Javascript was significant.  The trick to me was getting it to upload the modified surface.  I'm not sure how much of that would be visible in the postback.  If you're interested in contributing some features to the asp.net html canvas, please check my [HTML5 ASP project](http://html5asp.sourceforge.net/).